# CMD what does /im (taskkill)?

Tags: cmd, taskkill

I just read the following command:

`taskkill /f /im something.exe`

I read that `/f` forces the task to close, but what does `/im` do?

Comment: 3 downvotes without anyone telling him why? Hans, you were downvoted here because you didn't do any research on the topic. As you can see in the answers, all you needed to do was a little bit of research and you would have found your answer. On SE it's expected you research before asking.

Comment: Okay, I tried searching for it again even though I solved it and I was just searching under the wrong keyword!

Comment: @Michael _3 downvotes without anyone telling him why?_ Yes, I hate that.  What do those people think it's going to achieve?  It just scares new people away.

Comment: @michaelhouse You are awesome, so is Paul Sanders.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It tells `taskkill` that the next parameter `something.exe` is an image name, a.k.a executable name

```
C:\>taskkill /?

TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
         { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/T] [/F]

Description:
    This tool is used to terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name.

Parameter List:
    /S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U    [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which the
                           command should execute.

    /P    [password]       Specifies the password for the given user
                           context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    /FI   filter           Applies a filter to select a set of tasks.
                           Allows "*" to be used. ex. imagename eq acme*

    /PID  processid        Specifies the PID of the process to be terminated.
                           Use TaskList to get the PID.

    /IM   imagename        Specifies the image name of the process
                           to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used
                           to specify all tasks or image names.

    /T                     Terminates the specified process and any
                           child processes which were started by it.

    /F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).

    /?                     Displays this help message.
```

Comment: Thanks for the list, but now you make me feel uneasy if I should use /t too, for taskkilling the explorer.exe. Does it have child processes?

Comment: And if I kill a kill a task with task manager , which parameters are added?

Comment: Killing taskmgr with /T will not kill anything else unless you used TM's File > New Task option to run something.  /T on explorer.exe is another story!  Most likely anything you launched as a user is a child of explorer.exe

Comment: No, I mean when I open the task manager to kill a process, how is it killed?

Comment: End process would be /F, process tree would be /F /T.  It force closes as can be seen by tying something in a blank notepad document.  A normal close process would open the "Save?" prompt.  A force close disregards anything the process may do for cleanup and simply terminates it.  taskmgr likely uses the PID so as to not kill all instances of same-named executables, only the single instance in question.

Comment: I see, so what would be the best way to kill the explorer?

Comment: Just kill explorer and not the tree.  You may need to manually re-launch it with task manager (File > New Task) or command prompt if you have that open (type `explorer`) as it sometimes will not auto-re-launch

Comment: Okay, I will! But just out of interest, in which case would I kill the child processes too?

Comment: Maybe a program installer you want to abort, these tend to launch child processes.  But this may leave your system in a broken state.  Some multi-process apps like Chrome or newer IE w/ the proper settings open every tab in its own process...

Comment: When I try to execute, it says /F and /IM are not recognised as an internal command

Answer (score 8):

it allows you to kill a task based on the image name like taskkill /im iexplore.exe  or taskkill /im notepad.exe

Comment: This is the CORRECT answer, others just ignored the details about it.

Comment: I think what some people wonder is "What the heck is an Image Name?"  It's the exe name and extensiopn, sans the file path to the exe.

Answer (score 6):

If you type the executable name and a `/?` switch at the command line, there is typically help information available. Doing so with `taskkill /?` provides the following, for instance:

```
TASKKILL [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
         { [/FI filter] [/PID processid | /IM imagename] } [/T] [/F]

Description:
    This tool is used to terminate tasks by process id (PID) or image name.

Parameter List:
    /S    system           Specifies the remote system to connect to.

    /U    [domain\]user    Specifies the user context under which the
                           command should execute.

    /P    [password]       Specifies the password for the given user
                           context. Prompts for input if omitted.

    /FI   filter           Applies a filter to select a set of tasks.
                           Allows "*" to be used. ex. imagename eq acme*

    /PID  processid        Specifies the PID of the process to be terminated.
                           Use TaskList to get the PID.

    /IM   imagename        Specifies the image name of the process
                           to be terminated. Wildcard '*' can be used
                           to specify all tasks or image names.

    /T                     Terminates the specified process and any
                           child processes which were started by it.

    /F                     Specifies to forcefully terminate the process(es).

    /?                     Displays this help message.

Filters:
    Filter Name   Valid Operators           Valid Value(s)
    -----------   ---------------           -------------------------
    STATUS        eq, ne                    RUNNING |
                                            NOT RESPONDING | UNKNOWN
    IMAGENAME     eq, ne                    Image name
    PID           eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    PID value
    SESSION       eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    Session number.
    CPUTIME       eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    CPU time in the format
                                            of hh:mm:ss.
                                            hh - hours,
                                            mm - minutes, ss - seconds
    MEMUSAGE      eq, ne, gt, lt, ge, le    Memory usage in KB
    USERNAME      eq, ne                    User name in [domain\]user
                                            format
    MODULES       eq, ne                    DLL name
    SERVICES      eq, ne                    Service name
    WINDOWTITLE   eq, ne                    Window title

    NOTE
    ----
    1) Wildcard '*' for /IM switch is accepted only when a filter is applied.
    2) Termination of remote processes will always be done forcefully (/F).
    3) "WINDOWTITLE" and "STATUS" filters are not considered when a remote
       machine is specified.

Examples:
    TASKKILL /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKILL /PID 1230 /PID 1241 /PID 1253 /T
    TASKKILL /F /IM cmd.exe /T 
    TASKKILL /F /FI "PID ge 1000" /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne untitle*"
    TASKKILL /F /FI "USERNAME eq NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /IM notepad.exe
    TASKKILL /S system /U domain\username /FI "USERNAME ne NT*" /IM *
    TASKKILL /S system /U username /P password /FI "IMAGENAME eq note*"
```

You can also find this information, as well as documentation for most of the other command-line utilities, in the [Microsoft TechNet Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`im` is **"image process name"**
example `/f /im notepad.exe` is specified to kill image process name (program) notepad.exe

Answer (score 1):

See [the doc](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true) : it will close all running tasks using the executable file `something.exe`, more or less like linux' `killall`